# How to handle state transitions in a React / Flux component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-machine, flux, refluxjs

Given I have an AJAX based search field that reacts on user input, requests search results from a backend via AJAX, shows the results in a dropdown below the search field, allows navigation through the search results via cursor keys and reacts on `esc` key presses in an intelligent way.

Since the current Backbone based component is broken in many ways, I'd like to reimplement that search component using `React` and maybe `Flux` architecture.

During planning it turned out, that my component has at least a number of 10 different states (maybe even more), it has to react to `actions` triggered by user inputs, and as well to `actions` triggered by asynchronous server responses.

**Question1**: Should I model all state in a `store` instead of a the parent component? That meant, that every user input changes the stores state, for example the `:searchQuery`, `:searchResults` and my parent view component reacts to that state changes?

**Question2**: Or should I model all state in the parent component itself and omit a `store`, `dispatcher` and `actions` completely?

**Question3**: Independently from handling state in a `store` or in the parent component itself, it turned out, that the component itself can have at least 10 different states, and there should only be a certain number of transitions allowed. Usually, I'd pull in a statemachine implementation here, model all `:states` and allowed `:transitions` and execute transitions everytime an action is received by the `store` or a callback method is called in the parent component. What is the correct `React way` to handle `states` and `transitions` between these `states` in a component?

**Question4**: Which is the to-go-state-of-the-art `Flux` implementation for Javascript? I have seen [reflux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflux) so far, but I'm not sure, that's my poison.

I am open to all kind of suggestions here.

Comment: I have some similar questions.  I have a form that doesn't get saved until the save button is clicked.  Should I have the component mutate its state and only call an action when the store (or other components) need to know? Should the component notify the store every time the user enters input? Should the component have current state, and the store to be outdated until it should be pushed to persistence (or some more complex logic is needed)?  Would that make the source of truth confusing?

Answer (score 1):

I am building a similar component in `React` with `flux` right now and I have worked with `Backbone` extensively in the past so hopefully I give you some insight.

My guess is that your `Backbone` solution had a model local to your search view that built `:searchQuery` when the field(s) were updated. On the ajax callback you most likely just directly updated the `:searchResults`.

**1-2:**

With `flux` there ends up being a bit more boilerplate code, but in my experience if I don't build a store to start with I always regret it. That being said I would make a `SearchStore` for the `:searchResults` and keep the `:searchQuery` in the state of the parent component.

This way when you are ready to call your search you use a view action `SearchViewActions.getSearchResults(:searchQuery)` which makes the ajax call and in the callback calls `SearchServerActions.receiveSearchResults(:searchQuery, :searchResults)` and updates the store. Then your results component can listen for `Store` changes and call `SearchStore.getResults()` when it sees the change. This helps modularize the two sub-components, where as option **2** would tightly couple the two components and make it harder for outside component reuse.

**3:**

I like your solution of the state-machine, that you can just ask if you are allowed to make a transition and return a set of properties to update or a function to execute call `setState({...})` based on that information.

**4:**

[Reflux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflux) looks great, as it seems to reduce the boilerplate quite a bit. Reflux may or may not perform as well as stock `Flux` however.

Let me know how it goes, as your strategy may help me improve my structure.